# WSL2 + visual studio code нету прав

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, wsl, wsl2

WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Стоит плагин WSL
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl

в терминале "visual studio code" wsl пишу `code /var/www/` открывается новое окно не могу не чего создать

Окно с ошибкой

`Не удается записать файл "vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu/var/www/test.php" (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/test.php')`

Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Каким образом запускаете IDE VSCode? Пробовали из консоли WSL набрать code, и уже в этой среде работаь? (по идее так правильнее  работать с WSL)

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что у вас есть достаточно прав для записи в директорию `/var/www/`. Вы можете установить права на запись командой `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/`